# Medal bug: Linking to wrong question

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just got my first "Teacher" medal on EE. It's displayed in my profile overview under newest badges. If I click on it, it says it was awared for. [Arduino Stepper Motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1/arduino-stepper-motor)

[image: Img]

So apparently the correct question ID is not set here and it defaults to 1 or something like that.

Comment: I agree that it looks like a bug.  When you click on "Learn more", it shows the correct Answer that earned you the badge.

Comment: For convenience, [here is the direct link to your Activity page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/266908/max?tab=topactivity)

Comment: Oh, and try not to earn any new badges while this is investigated :)

Comment: @toolic, ok will try ;)

Comment: Related MetaSO? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311679/error-in-link-inside-tooltip-of-newest-badge

Comment: Related MetaSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296534/profile-page-links-to-random-answer-for-my-awarded-great-answer-badge

Comment: Yes, seems to be the same bug. Except their medal links to questtions/7 and /9 on their respective SE site. Apparently not fixed in 5 years ;)

Comment: I added a comment to the MetaSE post.  Maybe that will get an update.

Comment: Adding status-review for the team to look into this after @toolic raised this in a related previous report. Thanks for raising this again.

Comment: Ok, since someone upvoted this post, I now got a "Quorum" bagde and the bug is no longer reproduceable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed. More details (and haiku) [on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371004/51).